# Django Treebread admin AttributeError - 'Page' object has no attribute 'page_ptr_id'

Tags: django, tree, structure, admin, wagtail

Please help. Stuck and confused.

Trying to use Django Treebread admin to see the tree structure of Journal objects, which inherits from class Page in wagtail. Page inherits from MP_Node in Treebread.

models.py

```
from wagtail.core.models import Page
class Journal(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from treebeard.admin import TreeAdmin
from treebeard.forms import movenodeform_factory
from .models import Journal

class MyAdmin(TreeAdmin):
    form = movenodeform_factory(Journal)

admin.site.register(Journal, MyAdmin)
```

In Django admin, click Jounal and get error msg as below:

```
AttributeError at /admin/journal/journal/
'Page' object has no attribute 'page_ptr_id'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/journal/journal/
Django Version: 2.2.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Page' object has no attribute 'page_ptr_id'
Exception Location: C:\Users\Freedom\Anaconda3\envs\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py in url_for_result, line 473
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Freedom\Anaconda3\envs\myvenv\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['D:\\Python\\Django\\m4ever',
 'C:\\Users\\Freedom\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myvenv\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Freedom\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myvenv\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Freedom\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myvenv\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Freedom\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myvenv',
 'C:\\Users\\Freedom\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myvenv\\lib\\site-packages']
```

page_ptr_id is actually the Django auto-generated field name for the one-to-one relation from the specific Journal class to the base Page model. Tried define it explicitly in Journal as:

```
page_ptr_id = models.OneToOneField(Page, on_delete=models.CASCADE, parent_link=True)
```

But still get similar error msg, displaying as

```
'Page' object has no attribute 'page_ptr_id_id'
```

Answer (score 4):

Essentially you're asking Treebeard to do something impossible here - there is no tree structure of Journal objects, it's a tree structure of Page objects that may contain other page types besides Journal. What's happening internally in Treebeard is something along the lines of:

- TreeAdmin calls `Journal.get_tree()` to fetch the full tree for the Journal model
- `get_tree` finds that the tree structure for Journal is actually defined on the Page model
- `get_tree` calls `Page.objects.all()` and gets back a queryset of basic Page objects
- TreeAdmin (which is expecting a queryset of Journal objects) tries to display the data of these Page objects as if they were Journal instances, and fails because various expected fields (such as `page_ptr_id`) are missing.

As a rule, tree operations such as `get_tree` or `get_children` will always return basic Page objects, because there's no way for the query to know in advance which page types will be included in the results. If `Journal.get_tree()` tried to be smarter and only returned `Journal` objects, you'd end up with a tree with holes in it wherever non-Journal pages exist.

Within the Django admin, your options are:

- Register a TreeAdmin view for `Page` rather than `Journal` - this will allow you to see and modify the complete structure, but won't let you access the specific fields of Journal
- Use a regular `ModelAdmin` instead of `TreeAdmin` - this will let you view and edit the `Journal` entries as a flat list. (In this case you may need to exclude Treebeard's internal fields such as `path` and `depth` from being editable - modifying them directly is a bad idea.)

Comment: So glad hearing from the famous gasman & thank you! Your explanation & instructions are so right. Want to upvote your answer, but I have too less reputation to do that. Just a note to anyone facing similar issue - When define a custom admin, must first unregister the default Page model admin before registering the TreeAdmin.
admin.site.unregister(Page)